Git ignore does not recognize a node modules file, I'm not able to push my file to git because its exceeds file size limit
I want to push my project to Github, and I have a gitignore file to track my node modules so it won't be pushed to github.
But I'm getting an error pushing my files to github because a folder in node_modules exceeds github file size limit. But my node_modules is also in my .gitignore. I don't know my git is not able to track the file.
remote: error: File node_modules/@next/swc-win32-x64-msvc/next-swc.win32-x64-msvc.node is 117.24 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.

I'll be glad to get help on this so I can push my project to github.

Git is actually tracking the file.... That is the problem.... .gitignore does not affect tracked files.... Probably the .gitignore file was created/added after the file github is complaining about had been added in history already

compress your file and zip it and then upload it

It doesn't solve the problem.. what if I want to make new commits ?.. will I have to zip everytime ?

That won't solve the problem.... The file with over 100 MBs is already in history, it has to be removed from history.

A .gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. User doen't wand to add it in git
